# Run docker container with a different command in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I want to initially execute `app:rake db:setup` from GitLab so the db could be initialized.

Snippet from my GitLab YAML (init-db.yaml)

```
...
        name: gitlab
        image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9
        command:
        - app:rake db:setup
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gfs-vol-gitlab
          mountPath: /home/git/data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        resources: {}
      volumes:
...
```

But when i check the status of the pod, i get the following error message:

```
...
Command:
      app:rake db:setup
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"app:rake db:setup\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
...
```

Snippet from [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
...
...
EXPOSE 22/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp

VOLUME ["${GITLAB_DATA_DIR}", "${GITLAB_LOG_DIR}"]
WORKDIR ${GITLAB_INSTALL_DIR}
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["app:start"]
```

Snippet from [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/entrypoint.sh)

```
...
...
case ${1} in
  app:init|app:start|app:sanitize|app:rake)
...
```

UPDATE:
When i run this:

```
command:
        - "app:rake" 
        - "db:setup"
```

I get:

```
to open log file "/var/log/pods/5b604971-b5ac-11e7-9ee5-021bfed3b32a/gitlab_0.log": open /var/log/pods/5b604971-b5ac-11e7-9ee5-021bfed3b32a/gitlab_0.log: no such file or directory
```

When i try this:

```
command:
        - "/bin/sh"
        args:
        - "-c"
        - "app:rake db:setup"
```

I get: `/bin/sh: 1: app:rake: not found`

This [link](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#restoring-backups) describes running `app:rake db:setup` command to setup database.

I earlier tried running this command outside Kubernetes and it worked fine using the code shown below:

```
docker run --name gitlab -it --rm \
    --link gitlab-postgresql:postgresql --link gitlab-redis:redisio \
    --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 \
    --env 'GITLAB_PORT=80' \
    --env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=64_bit_key_A' \
    --env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=64_bit_key_B' \
    --env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=64_bit_key_C' \
    --volume /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data \
    sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9 app:rake db:setup
```

UPDATE_1:

```
$ kubectl describe pod gitlab-1108406018-3lvh7
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                      Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled              18m                default-scheduler         Successfully assigned gitlab-1108406018-3lvh7 to rancher-a
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  18m                kubelet, rancher-a  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-qv8dm"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  18m                kubelet, rancher-a  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-304c48a5-b430-11e7-9ee5-021bfed3b32a"
  Normal   Pulling                17m                kubelet, rancher-a  pulling image "docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9"
  Normal   Pulled                 16m                kubelet, rancher-a  Successfully pulled image "docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9"
  Normal   Pulled                 2m (x7 over 16m)   kubelet, rancher-a  Container image "docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                2m (x8 over 16m)   kubelet, rancher-a  Created container
  Normal   Started                2m (x8 over 16m)   kubelet, rancher-a  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                8s (x56 over 15m)  kubelet, rancher-a  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  FailedSync             8s (x56 over 15m)  kubelet, rancher-a  Error syncing pod
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might just be a mixup of the Pod spec. In Kubernetes, the `command` is the equivalent of the Docker `ENTRYPOINT` and the `args` are the equivalent of `CMD`. In your case, I think you want:

```
...
        name: gitlab
        image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9
        command:
        - "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"
        args:
        - "app:rake"
        - "db:setup"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gfs-vol-gitlab
          mountPath: /home/git/data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        resources: {}
      volumes:
...
```

Comment: You are completely right. The [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) also shows a table about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andy for the help! :) One query though: i see the db initialization did happen but when i check the pod status, it keeps failing. I have posted the output of `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` in UPDATE_1 above. Any idea why this is happening? Although i had to run this only once (as it was just for the db initialization) and i will delete the deployment now, just wanted to know why this error is showing up. Also, for such one-time task, is creating deployment the right way? I'm skeptical about my approach.

Comment: I think creating a deployment is fine if you will be eventually updating the image version and are running multiple pods. But the added error probably just warrants a new question. It seems like a new error to me that isn't related to the initial error.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This is not the right answer. Please refer to Andy Shinn's answer.

---

Each command should be an item inside the command array. As you want to execute two commands, try this:

```
...
        name: gitlab
        image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9
        command:
        - "app:rake" 
        - "db:setup"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gfs-vol-gitlab
          mountPath: /home/git/data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        resources: {}
      volumes:
...
```

You can also use the `args` parameter to write your `app:rake db:setup` command pair in one line (by basically forcing the commands to run in a shell context):

```
...
        name: gitlab
        image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9
        command:
        - "/bin/sh"
        args:
        - "-c"
        - "app:rake db:setup"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gfs-vol-gitlab
          mountPath: /home/git/data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        resources: {}
      volumes:
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @fishi. I too came across [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) few mins after posting my query. :) I tried your suggestion and have updated my post. Please check UPDATE section.

Comment: @Technext the first error message (multiple commands) is not from the pod itself, but rather from k8s not finding the log files from that pod on the host machine. The second error (using `args`) looks to me like ruby or sth necessary to trigger the command is not within the shell's path. Does it make a difference if you run `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`?